# Can we deploy SharePoint framework assets anywhere other than SharePoint CDN and Azure CDN?

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepointframework

Can we deploy SPFx assets anywhere other than SharePoint CDN and Azure CDN?

Answer (score 1):

SPFx assets basically can be hosted in any file storage - it can be a centralised SharePoint site, O365 CDN, external CDN service like Azure CDN, Cloudflare CDN, Amazon S3 but also it can be a custom file server hosted anywhere basically (any hosting provider, on premise infrastructure etc). There's basically no limitation to where you can host your SPFx assets. You just have to ensure that your `cdnBasePath` is properly set and that all the files were copied to the correct destination.

Source: [Deploy your SharePoint client-side web part to Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/deploy-web-part-to-cdn#deploy-to-other-cdns)

Comment: So, if I have my files inside the SharePoint Style Library, what should I do?

Comment: Probably just provide the folder's address to the `cdnBasePath` property